# what would cause a compiled .exe not to execute?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

So I have two C# programs both referencing the same custom library. In each program is a call to a method in that library. In one program this method call is attached to a button press, and in the other it is under the Main method so it should run with the .exe is executed... except it doesn't. When I press the button to call the method in the one program it works like a charm, but the call in the Main method of the other program doesn't.

here are my code snippets:

Method call inside windows form application (DOES work)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using p_controller;

/*p_controller is a custom library that contains the static method 
restart_all which restarts some system processes*/

namespace p_restarter_form : Form
{

class p_restart_form
{
   public p_restart_form()
   {
      //constructor does some things in actual program
    }

    private void restart_all_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       p_controls.restart_all();
    }
 }
}
```

Full code of windows application (does NOT work)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using proxy_controller;

namespace p_restarter
{
class p_restart
{
    static void Main()
    {
        p_controls.restart_all();
    }
}
}
```

So the form app compiles into an .exe which when ran shows a form with a button and when I click the button the restart_all() method is called and the processes get restarted. The second program is a windows application that compiles into an .exe which when ran calls the Main() method, which in turn calls the same restart_all() method.

The form works, the windows app does not... it does absolutely nothing when executed.

Comment: What is `proxy_controls.restart_all`?

Comment: Are you sure that you reference correct versions of the library? What do you mean by "not executing"? Have your tried to put a breakpoint onto the problem code and [step into](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)?

Comment: And more importantly, what does not happen that you expect to happen?

Comment: What symptoms of the problem? How do you know that it does not work? Does it throw some exception?

Comment: What happens if you set a breakpoint on your method, start your program in a debugger and after reaching the breakpoint you enable all  exceptions under `Debug - Exceptions`?

Comment: basically the snippets show me executing a function that is part of a library I created. The snippets however are from two different programs, one calls the method on a button press and the other runs it from Main(). But it is the same method call to the same library which is referenced properly in both programs. Except it works on the button press... but the stand alone program that calls from the Main() method doesnt work. let see if I can make the code more clear.

Comment: I changed it to a console app and added Console.Writeline("TEST"); after the static method call and it does write the line, so the code is being executed its just not doing anything. Thats so bizarre!! The form app calls it in exactly the same way and works... I don't get it.

Answer (score 0):

By the code-snippets it's hard to judge what you are doing.
It seems like proxy_controls is not initialized in your Main-method.
The second snippet would not compile.
There should be an initialization with new for the proxy_controls thing. 
Or,  if it's a class member of the posmon_restart class an initialization of that class in the Main method.

Comment: I suppose it is the name of a class with a static method restart_all(), so this might work. But obviously it is missing some initialization that has been done by the second approach

Comment: its not missing the initialization, I just didn't copy that part in here (long). The first snippet is part of another class that has proper initialization. And the restart_all function does in fact call a static method from the proxy_controls library (which is properly referenced in both programs). Looking at the code I see no difference at all between the two implementations.

Comment: Ok, I give it another shot. Are you sure  your Main method isn't returning instantly after having executed the proxy_controls.restart_all()? In the first example with the button_click handler the Windows Message loop would be running unti somebody calls Application.Exit(). Have you tried to insert traces before and after your call to proxy_controls.restart_all()? Add a Console.ReadKey() after the restart_all() to keep your program from exiting instantly.